# How to configure timeout when getting items from DynamoDB

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I want to put a timeout when getting an item from the DynamoDB in Go. I tried to provide the http.Client with 500ms timeout, but it did not work.

Here's how I configured the Timeout. But when I use `GetItem` and it was hanging there.

```
func LocalDynamo() *dynamodb.DynamoDB {
    creds := credentials.NewStaticCredentials("123", "123", "")
    awsConfig := &aws.Config{
        Credentials: creds,
        Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
        Endpoint:    aws.String("http://127.0.0.1:8001"),
        HTTPClient: &http.Client{
            Timeout: 500 * time.Millisecond,
        },
    }
    awsSession := session.Must(session.NewSession(awsConfig))
    return dynamodb.New(awsSession)
}
```

Comment: Also provide socket timeout. But I doubt your query is taking a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context with a Timeout.

```golang
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.TODO(), 500*time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()

getOuput, err := c.GetItemWithContext(aws.Context(ctx), input)
```

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/#DynamoDB.GetItemWithContext

Your requests shouldn't take 500ms though. Seems rather slow for DynamoDB.